# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\modelo\UsuarioDao.php on line 27

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Me surge el siguiente error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\iedan\modelo\UsuarioDao.php on line 27.

No se a que se debe, aquí dejo la parte del codigo que me bota el error

```
<?php 

include 'conexion.php';
include '../entidades/Usuario.php';


class UsuarioDao extends Conexion{
    protected static $cnx;

    public static function getConexion(){
        self::$cnx = Conexion::conectar();
    }

    private static function desconectar(){
        self::$cnx = null;
    }

//metodo para validar el login
    public static function login($usuario){

        $query = "SELECT id, nombre, usuario, email, privilegio, fecha_registro FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password";

        self::getConexion();

        $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);

        $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario); //aqui esta el error
        $resultado->bindParam(":password", $password);

        $resultado->excecute();

        if(count($resultado)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: ¿Desde dónde llamas al método `login`?  Le estás pasando una instancia de la clase `Usuario`, pero el método lo que espera es una cadena con el nombre del usuario (supongo), de ahí el error: `Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string` o sea, el objeto de la clase `Usuario` no se pudo convertir a cadena.